# SQL Temp DB Disappearing using Python pyodbc Queries

Tags: python, sql-server, database, temp-tables, pyodbc

How do I keep my connection to a SQL server database alive when running scripts from a Python pyodbc program?

The reason I ask is because I want to automate a task at my job that uses a Temp DB to store information, and then uses Excel to refresh its data based on those temp databases. However, when I run the query through pyodbc in my python script, the databases fall off automatically, and I'm assuming that's because it kills the connection after it's done running.

Is there a way to keep the connection open in Python so that I can still refresh my Excel spreadsheets?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using @table_variables or #temp_tables? You might want to consider using a ##global_temp_table, although those will be deleted during a SQL Server restart. It sounds like what you're asking for is a temp table which persists, which sort of defeats the point of the temp table. Have you considered just doing a SELECT INTO for table creation, and having a clean up routine?

Comment: If you are using an @table or a #table, they won't be visible to the Excel spreadsheet unless you update that sheet through the Python application, since their scope (who can see / use them) is only on the connection that created them. And a ##table is visible to all, but disappears when the last connection to the table closes. I recommend an actual table that can accept the data, and reading it from there.

Comment: @LaughingVergil thank you for the input! Unfortunately, the process was not set up by me, and I do not have write access (yet) to create a table in the database, so I'm stuck with using a ##table for now. Why is it that I can refresh it through the Python application but not from the Excel sheet?

Comment: @FlipperPA, unfortunately I do not have the rights to create a table, so I have to use a ##table for now. I will most definitely consider that options + cleanup provided I get access to create a table.

Comment: Have you tried creating your table in TempDB? You would be surprised what permissions you have there. You will just have to handle the cases where the table either exists already (clear it before reloading it) or doesn't exist (create it.)  Just CREATE TABLE TempDB.dbo.MyTableName ...